# how to remove the rule "|" between name and title in \makecvtitle from moderncvbanking style?

Tags: latex

i want to start by saying that i am no programmer and that i do not know a lot about it,
i tried to make my own cv using latex as a first experience, you will find screenshots of what i did below and then i'll explain what i don't understand ;

this is the code in the model i found :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D06lw.png)
and this is how it displays my name and title :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gagIc.png)

what i would like to do, is to delete the \rule "|" that it between my name and my title,
i did some research and understood that the banking style affects the command \makecvtitle, what i do not know is how can i delete it ?

here is the code as asked in the comments :

```
    \documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}        
    \moderncvstyle{banking}                            
    \moderncvcolor{blue}      

    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                      
    \usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

    \usepackage{import}


    \name{Hichem}{RAHMANI\\}

    \title{Certified SAP Consultant}                                
    \phone[mobile]{+213 540 323 550}                   
    \email{h.rahmani04221995@gmail.com}                                


    \begin{document}

    \makecvtitle
    \end{document}
```

i would be more than grateful if anyone could show me this,

thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add a compilable [mre] to your question - please do this by pasting it into a code block and not as image.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz i just did as you asked sir.

Comment: Thanks for editing your post! (... but please don't call me sir :) )

Comment: i am  so sorry if you felt offended or anything, it was not my intention.

Comment: Don't worry, no harm done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redefine the head like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}        
\moderncvstyle{banking}                            
\moderncvcolor{blue}      

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                      
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\usepackage{import}

\makeatletter
\@initializecommand{\makehead}{%
  \setlength{\makeheaddetailswidth}{0.8\textwidth}%
  \hfil%
  \parbox{\makeheaddetailswidth}{%
    \centering%
    % name and title
    \namestyle{\@firstname~\@lastname}\linebreak%
    \vskip-1.5ex%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\titlestyle{\@title}}% \isundefined doesn't work on \@title, as LaTeX itself defines \@title (before it possibly gets redefined by \title) 
    % optional detailed information
    \if@details{%
      \\%
      \addressfont\color{color2}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\addtomakeheaddetails{\addresssymbol\@addressstreet}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\addtomakeheaddetails[~--~]{\@addresscity}}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and \addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\addtomakeheaddetails[~--~]{\@addresscountry}}%
        \flushmakeheaddetails\@firstmakeheaddetailselementtrue\\}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@born}}{}{\addtomakeheaddetails{\bornsymbol\@born}}%
      \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
        \addtomakeheaddetails{\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\addtomakeheaddetails{\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\addtomakeheaddetails{\homepagesymbol\httpslink{\@homepage}}}%
      \collectionloop{socials}{% the key holds the social type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the link
        \addtomakeheaddetails{\csname\collectionloopkey socialsymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\addtomakeheaddetails{\@extrainfo}}%
      \flushmakeheaddetails}\fi}\\[2.5em]}% need to force a \par after this to avoid weird spacing bug at the first section if no blank line is left after \makehead

\makeatother


\name{Hichem}{RAHMANI}

\title{Certified SAP Consultant}                                
\phone[mobile]{+213 540 323 550}                   
\email{h.rahmani04221995@gmail.com}                                


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle
\end{document}
```